# Export spatial data from sql server to ESRI shapefile

Tags: sql-server, spatial, esri, osgeo

I wanna export a spatial data from sql to ESRI shapefile and i have an issue :

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" " C:\Users\sqlexport.shp " 
"MSSQL:server=PORT_7FMW8H2;database=testdbspatial;trusted_connection=yes;     
"-sql "select * from DRShape" -overwrite
```

> ERROR 1: Failed to create directory  C:\Users\sqlexport.shp  for shapefile datastore.
>   ERROR 1: ESRI Shapefile driver failed to create  C:\Users\sqlexport.shp

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the leading and trailing spaces around your path:
" C:\Users\sqlexport.shp "
needs to be:
"C:\Users\sqlexport.shp"

You also probably want to add the flag
 -t_srs ESPG:4326(or whatever your projection espg code is) 
this will ensure that ogr2ogr writes the .prj file most GIS programs will look for when opening a .shp file.